# Blowfish encryption: Java vs. Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, jboss, puppet, blowfish

I am trying to generate some encrypted JBoss data source passwords from Puppet (Ruby). JBoss uses [this library (see line 149)](https://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=332) to encrypt / decrypt the passwords (using Blowfish with a predefined key compiled in the Java code).

Now, researching a bit I found that, as default, javax.crypto uses for blowfish the following parameters: Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding.

By default, Ruby's OpenSSL library does not make any padding at all (simply refuses the key if it is not a multiple of 8). I tried to do the padding manually and here is my complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'openssl'

key = 'jaas is the way'

ciph = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('bf-ecb').encrypt
ciph.key = key + (8 - key.length % 8).chr * (8 - key.length % 8)

b = ciph.update(ARGV[0]) + ciph.final()
puts b.unpack('H*')
```

I tried to implement the PKCS5 padding the same way as I saw it implemented in Python in a similar (Python vs. Java Blowfish) question here on SO by adding chr(number of bytes until the length is multiple of 8) until the length of the string is multiple of 8. For this specific key, it is supposed to add exactly one chr(1) and when trying to debug, it seems to do it just fine.

The thing is that my Ruby code is giving different results to the ones obtained by the code in the Picketbox library in Java.

EDIT:
Here are some conclusions I got after running more tests:

- If both the key and the plain text to be encrypted are 16 bytes long, the results are fine
- We tried with a 16 bytes long plain text string to be encrypted and a 15 bytes key. Then we padded (both pre and post) the key in Ruby with all characters with ASCII code from 0 to 255 and none of the results were matching the encrypted text we got in Java. This makes no sense at all because, if Java would simply pad the key with whatever, it would add a character to the beginning or the end of the original key. The only logical explanation could be if Java does manipulate the key string by other means, other than appending a character.

Comment: Are the results the same if the key is a multiple of 8 to begin with?

Comment: Nope, the results are not the same, unfortunately. And even if in the Java code I put Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding when initializing the Cipher, the results are even more awkward as I get a shorter string with Java in that case, which makes me think that Ruby also does some kind of padding up to a computed value.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189406/ruby-blowfish-difference-in-the-last-digits

Comment: @UriAgassi, the solution posted by the user Jasper on that page is not working. First because he's using spaces to pad. If I replace his padding method with mine, I get exactly the same result as I get with my code. Also, it is not the same problem because in the case of his question he was getting everything alright except the last block. In my case, nothing is fine, which makes sense if the key is differently used/processed by Java in the backstage. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Try to pad the plaintext data...

Comment: Well, it was an idea that triggered more tests. Let me put them in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Worakarn Isaratham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823254/worakarn-isaratham)'s answer is 100% correct, however, I'd like to provide an implementation for this problem using the standard OpenSSL library:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'openssl'

def JBossPasswordEncrypt(s)
    ciph = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('bf-ecb').encrypt

    # https://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=332 Line 153
    ciph.key_len = 15
    ciph.key = 'jaas is the way'

    # PKCS5 Padding
    s = s + (8 - s.length % 8).chr * (8 - s.length % 8)

    # Split the secret in chunks of 8 and encrypt it
    e = s.scan(/.{8}/).map { |block| ciph.update(block).unpack('H*') }

    # Convert the bytes array into a signed number
    en = e.join.to_i(16)
    en = en - (2 ** (en.size * 8)) if en >= (2 ** (en.size * 8 - 1))

    # Return the result in hex (as string)
    return en.to_s(16)
end

puts JBossPasswordEncrypt(ARGV[0])
```

Thank you very much for the help to everyone!

EDIT: I added conversion to a signed number, just like Java does. Not so nice but it works.

EDIT: I wrote it as a method with easier to understand syntax and comments.

Comment: oh, I didn't know you could set the key length like that. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Look like the Java Blowfish does no padding to the key at all; it just starts over from the first byte once it reaches the end of the key. (Try using keys "abc, then "abcabc" and see what happens.)

I suggest looking into this [Crypt19](https://github.com/coffeejunk/crypt19) gem - their Blowfish implementation accepts key that is not a multiple of 8. But they only offer CBC mode, so you need to implement ECB yourself. Should be pretty easy - just:

- pad the message (like how you pad the key)
- split the message into 8-byte blocks, and
- call `encrypt_block` for each block

EDIT: okay, here's the code. This produces identical output to Java version, at least for this "Hello, world!" input.

```
require 'crypt/blowfish' 

secret = "Hello, world!"
blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new("jaas is the way")
padded_secret = secret + (8 - secret.length % 8).chr * (8 - secret.length % 8)
encrypted = padded_secret.scan(/.{8}/).map{|block| blowfish.encrypt_block(block).unpack('H*')}.join
puts encrypted #print "17a0aef80205dd34d08dbf27a0101c9c"
```

Comment: According to your statement (which makes sense and I've seen similar implementations in the past) my key shall be "jaas is the wayj", with the "j" at the end being the completion to make the 128 bits. Using an 8 bytes message (to avoid padding issues) and this key, I still get different results in Ruby and Java. In fact, as you can see, I generated 256 encrypted strings in Ruby, by appending all bytes from 0 to 255 to the 15 bytes key and none of them resulted in the string generated by the Java code, which makes me wonder if Java does some other manipulations on the key or the message.

Comment: No, what you described is still padding, and that's not how it's implemented, at least according to the OpenJDK version ( http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/crypto/provider/BlowfishCrypt.java - see init method). It does no manipulation to the key at all, not padding or anything else, except for checking if it's too long. The key just doesn't have to be of multiple-of-8 length. So you can't use OpenSSL implementation. Take a look at my code - that produces exactly the same output for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using your solution, I also implemented it using the OpenSSL library.